# UITextField - message sent to deallocated instance "UIKBStringWideAttributeValueForKey:"

Tags: xcode, ios6, uitextfield

After enabling Zombie Objects I am able to see the following error when I try to edit a UITextField (textLvl):

```
2013-01-13 13:27:10.509 testob[18418:907] *** -[NSConcreteMutableAttributedString
 _UIKBStringWideAttributeValueForKey:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x2066a1f0
```

I have posted the portion of code that is causing the issue below, it seems to specifically be the "textField.text = self.storeText;" part - as when I comment this out the problem goes away.

You may be able to tell I am not the most experienced iOS dev, why would my UITextView deallocate after I've set the text? Help please!

Also, I've never heard of "_UIKBStringWideAttributeValueForKey" before - any ideas?

Thanks all!

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    NSLog(@"Text began editing");
 self.storeText = textField.text;
  textField.text = @"";

}

- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    if (textField == textLvl){

        if ([textField.text isEqualToString:@""]){
            textField.text = self.storeText;
            NSLog(@"No Text");
        }

        self.conv = [textField.text intValue];
        if (self.conv >= 101){
            textField.text = @"100";
            UIAlertView *successAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Oh no!" message:@"Can't be higher than 100." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
            [successAlert show]; }
        }}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might be a bug internal to the framework.  I suggest you add - `(BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField` and set the textfield text to nil and then reset the textfield text.

Comment: This is exactly what I did in the end and it solved the problem. Thanks.

Comment: @humblemenon :your answer helped me.but i have a question on this, in my UIView i have nearly 15 textFields , why i am getting this type of error for only 3 of them.

Answer (score 1):

I think the real answer here is that you're dealing with a UITextField that has been set to handle NSAttributedString rather than NSString. You'll notice if you're dealing with UITextField defined in a .xib, it's top property option is now "Text" with options Plain or Attributed.

If your text field was switched to attributed, you'll find this error happening if you continue to deal with the text field as if it were Plain.

Answer (score 1):

My textfield was in a xib file and it's delegate was hooked up to the files owner.  This was causing the crash for me, because the file's owner was NSObject.

I actually wanted to hook up the delegate to the cell, and not files owner.

Comment: The issue occurs in iOS 8, but is automatically taken care of in iOS 9. Anyways perfect answer to the point.

Answer (score 0):

Use instruments so see the retains/releases:

If you need to see where retains, releases and autoreleases occur for an object use instruments:

Run in instruments, in Allocations set "Record reference counts" on on (you have to stop recording to set the option). Cause the picker to run, stop recording, search for there ivar (datePickerView), drill down and you will be able to see where all retains, releases and autoreleases occurred.

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately I wasn't any good at putting this information to use. :(

Is this not something people have seen before?